# to generate years automatically in javascript dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I created javascript that generates years used in my dropdown menu. I want to  display current year and future years automatically. Does anyone know how to implement this?

```
<select id="selectElementId"></select>

<script>
    var min = 2012,
    max = 2021,
    select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

    for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
       var opt = document.createElement('option');
       opt.value = i;
       opt.innerHTML = i;
       select.appendChild(opt);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Some browsers might refuse to set `innerHTML` to `option` element, use `opt.text` instead.

Comment: Commenting as someone might find this helpful:
`
function getYearList(minYear, currentYear, selectElement){
 var max = currentYear, min = minYear;
 for (var i = min; i<=max; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = i;
  opt.innerHTML = i;
  selectElement.append(opt);
 }
       //selecting current year
 $(selectElement).val(max)
  .find("option[value=" + max +"]")
  .attr("selected","selected");
}
`
calling on page load
`
var selectElement = $('.select-class');
 getYearList('2015', currentYear, selectElement);
`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Date.getFullYear`. Example:

```
var min = new Date().getFullYear(),
    max = min + 9
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8fdh/

Answer (score 4):

You basically have it there already?

See fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/feedmeastraydog/5raMT/

```
var min = new Date().getFullYear();
    max = min + 20;
    select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}

select.value = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `new Date().getFullYear()` to get the current year:

```
var min = new Date().getFullYear();
var max = min + 20;
```